# Xamarin Studio for Mac has project templates, how to fix it?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I downloaded Xamarin Studio for the Mac.

When I try to create a project it does not give any of the template options that are shown on the website. When I try to use one of the few templates available it keeps the next button greyed out so I can't proceed.

Anybody know how to get this working properly?

Comment: Where did you download the Xamarin Studio from? Apart from Xamarin studio you need to install Xamarin.iOS/Android packages

Comment: I downloaded straight from their website and made sure the download included everything.

Comment: Could you post the Version information from Mac: Xamarin Studio > About Xamarin Studio > Show Details > Copy Information

Comment: === Xamarin Studio Community ===

Version 6.1.1 (build 17)
Installation UUID: cb6f53b1-ae4a-41c4-a28a-964a3849c6c7
Runtime:
 Mono 4.6.1 (mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/ef43c15) (64-bit)
 GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

 Package version: 406010005

=== NuGet ===

Version: 3.4.3.0

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Not Installed

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 8.1 (11544)
Build 8B62

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Not Installed

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Not Installed

=== Xamarin Android Player ===

Not Installed

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Not Installed

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments suggests that you do not have Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android installed.

You can get the installers at

- iOS - http://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-10.2.0.4.pkg
- Android - http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Mac/xamarin.android-7.0.1-2.pkg